# How can I set NSSegmentedControl background image?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

I want to set the `NSSegmentedControl` background image not the icon image.I subclass the `NSSegmentedCell` and rewrite the `drawSegment: inFrame: withView:` function.But this works bad.How can I do that?

update:
I want to set the half rect dark or light color background image.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing and overriding `drawSegment: inFrame: withView` works fine

```
- (void)drawSegment:(NSInteger)segment inFrame:(NSRect)frame withView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameBonjour];
    [image drawInRect:frame fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [super drawSegment:segment inFrame:frame withView:controlView];    
}
```

What else did you try?
Did you set the cell class for your segmented control correctly in Interface Builder?

Comment: I want to set the half rect dark or light color background image,not just add an image to the background.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your original question. Please update the question in order to explain the actual problem.